# How do you create an array of classes?

Tags: typescript, class

I want to make an array of classes in TypeScript. This is possible in vanilla JavaScript:

```
class A {
    constructor() {console.log('constructor');}
    a() {}
}

const array = [A];

new (array[0])(); // Prints 'constructor'
```

I want to make the array type safe using an interface. This is my attempt to implement this in TypeScript:

```
interface I {
    a();
}

class A implements I {
    constructor() {console.log('constructor')}
    a() {}
}

const array: I[] = [A];

new (array[0])();
```

When I compile this, I get this error:

```
Error:(16, 21) TS2322: Type 'typeof A' is not assignable to type 'I'.
  Property 'a' is missing in type 'typeof A'.
```

Because this error message mentions that `typeof A is not assignable to type 'I'`, it seems that arrays can not contain classes, as `typeof` is used for instantiated objects.

What I need is a way to group all my classes in a single variable without instantiating them, and be able to access the class by index. How can I achieve this in TypeScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interfaces define properties and method available on instances, so this would work:

```
 const array: I[] = [new A()];
```

It's not what you want, but it should demonstrate why it's not working: Class and instance are two different things.

What you want to say is "it's an array of types and new() will return an instance of I".

I think it should look like this:

```
class Test implements I {
    a() {}
}

interface I {
    a();
}

interface TI {
    new (): I;
}

const arr: TI[] = [Test];

const inst = new arr[0]();
```